# Limit Contact Form 7 hook (Before Send) to specific form

Tags: php, wordpress, salesforce, contact-form-7

I have a website with 3 form, but only two of these forms must enter information into the Salesforce database. How do I define which forms should use the hook and which shall without going through it?

Follow the code I'm using:

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'my_conversion' );
  function my_conversion( $contact_form ) {
    $title = $contact_form->title;
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

    if ( $submission ) {
        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
  }

      $email = $posted_data["your-email"];
      $name  = $posted_data["your-name"];
      $last  = $posted_data["your-lastname"];
      $phone = $posted_data["tel-71"];
      $description = $posted_data["your-message"];


        $post_items[] = 'oid=00D4000000xxxxx';
        $post_items[] = 'first_name=' . $name;
        $post_items[] = 'last_name=' . $last;
        $post_items[] = 'company=';
        $post_items[] = 'email=' . $email;
        $post_items[] = 'phone=' . $phone;  
        $post_items[] = 'description=' . $description;
        $post_items[] = '00N4000000XXXX=' . "Shopping";
        $post_items[] = '00N4000000xxxxxx=' . "1";
        $post_items[] = 'external=1';
        $post_items[] = 'lead_source=Shopping';

    $post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);

    $ch = curl_init( 'https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8' );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    curl_exec($ch); // Post to Salesforce
    curl_close($ch); // close cURL resource
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I had found this function:

`if ( $contact_form->id !== $myform_id )
        return;`
But I know very little about PHP. Where should I enter this line? Would you help me?

Thanks again.

Comment: I did like this:

`add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'my_conversion' );
  function my_conversion( $contact_form ) {
    $title = $contact_form->title;
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    $id = $contact_form->id();
 
 if ( $id==68 ) {
       $submission->skip_mail = true;
  }
 
   if ( $id==65 ) {
        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
  }

      (...)`


Now the form of ID = 65 normally recorded in Salesforce. But the ID = 68 does not send the email, is locked with the fields filled. What am I doing wrong? Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Hello. I got a solution, I do not think it’s the best but here is what I did:
I used the solution suggested by @takayukister. In case “$contact_form->title()”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution, I do not think it’s the best but here is what I did:

```
    add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'my_conversion' );
       function my_conversion( $contact_form ) {
       $title = $contact_form->title;
       $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

    if ( $submission ) {
        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
    }

    if ( 'FORM NAME' == $title ) {

          $email = $posted_data["your-email"];
          $name  = $posted_data["your-name"];
          $last  = $posted_data["your-lastname"];
          $phone = $posted_data["tel-71"];
          $description = $posted_data["your-message"];


            $post_items[] = 'oid=00D4000000xxxxx';
            $post_items[] = 'first_name=' . $name;
            $post_items[] = 'last_name=' . $last;
            $post_items[] = 'company=';
            $post_items[] = 'email=' . $email;
            $post_items[] = 'phone=' . $phone;  
            $post_items[] = 'description=' . $description;
            $post_items[] = '00N4000000XXXX=' . "Shopping";
            $post_items[] = '00N4000000xxxxxx=' . "1";
            $post_items[] = 'external=1';
            $post_items[] = 'lead_source=Shopping';

        $post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);

        $ch = curl_init('https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8' );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1 );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
        curl_exec($ch); // Post to Salesforce
        curl_close($ch); // close cURL resource
 }
```

I used the solution suggested by @takayukister. In case “$contact_form->title()”.

Just remember to change "FORM NAME" with the name of the form that you want to perform the action.

Thanks @takayukister!